# c# System invalid operation exception when running MYSQL

Tags: c#

Hi guys I want to show all data from Mysql to c# form on datatable but I always get this exception
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Fill: "

full code:

```
    public void testing()
    {

        DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
        dbc.OpenConnection();
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        string query1 = "select * from info;";

        MySqlCommand commander = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection);

        MySqlDataAdapter searcher = new MySqlDataAdapter(commander);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(connectionString, query1);
    }

    public DataTable GetData(string connectionString, string query1)
    {
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection))
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

That's my full code by I still get "connection must be valid and open"

Comment: Is there any more detail to the error? Why do you have two `MySqlCommand`s?

Comment: Without more context my best guess is that `connection` is null.

Comment: sorry I don't know I copy pasted someone's solution and experimented a bit.

Comment: I tried verifying connection it is open

Comment: "SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized" some detail of the exception

Comment: please paste in the whole error/exception, plus stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data) package, I hope it could be useful:

```
    using var con = new MySqlConnection(/*connection string goes here*/);
    con.Open();

    using var command = new MySqlCommand(/*query goes here*/, con);
    using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work in this way:

```
public DataTable GetData(string connectionString, string query)
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(reader);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very noob but how do you call/run this?

Comment: @cedie_asd by doing something like:  dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(connectionString, query1);

Comment: tried this but I'm very confused I received connection must be valid exception and I'm certain that it is open